# Can't webscrape with R the site of Fitch Ratings

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the website of Fitch Ratings and until now I can't get what I wanted: the list of ratings. When I scrape with **R** it returns the header of the website and in the body it gets an "iframe" from googleTagManager the "hide" the content that matters.

website: https://www.fitchratings.com/site/search?content=research&filter=RESEARCH%20LANGUAGE%5EPortuguese%2BGEOGRAPHY%5EAmericas%2BREPORT%20TYPE%5EHeadlines%5ERating%20Action%20Commentary

return:

```
[1] <head>\n<title>Search - Fitch Ratings</title>\n<!-- headerScripts --><!-- --><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; chars ...
[2] <body id="search-results">\n        <div id="privacy-policy-tos-modal-container"></div>\n        <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -- ...
_____________
```

What I want:

```
Date;Research;Type;Text

04 Sep 2019; Fitch afirma Rating de Qualidade(...);Rating Action Commentary;Fitch Ratings-Sao Paulo - 04 September 2019: A Fitch Ratings Afirmou hoje, o Rating de Qualidade de Gestão de Ivnestimento 'Excelente' (...)
02 Sep 2019; Fitch Eleva Rating (...); Rating Action Commentary; Fitch Ratings - Sao Paulo - 02 September 2019: A Fitch Ratings elevou hoje (...)
```

---

Code below

```
html_of_site <- read_html(url("https://www.fitchratings.com/site/search?content=research&filter=RESEARCH%20LANGUAGE%5EPortuguese%2BGEOGRAPHY%5EAmericas%2BREPORT%20TYPE%5EHeadlines%5ERating%20Action%20Commentary"))

html_of_site
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: Don't scrape this website.

Long Answer: Technically it is possible to scrape this site, but you need your code to *act like a human*. What this means is that you would need to convince Fitch Group's server that you are indeed a human visitor and not a bot.

To do this you need to:

- Send the same headers that your browser would send to the site
- Keep track of any cookies the site sends back to you and return them in subsequent requests if necessary
- Evaluate any scripts sent back by the server (to actually load the data you want).

I wasn't able to access the site policy for the thefitchgroup.com, but I assume it includes clauses about what bots are and are not allowed to do on the site. Since this company likely sells the data you are trying to scrape, you should probably avoid scraping this site.

In general, don't scrape sites without reading the site policies first. If the data you are scraping is not free without scraping it, then you probably shouldn't be scraping it.

Comment: The problem is not that the site actively prevents web-scraping, but dynamic content. (BTW I can't get the TOS either, but I too assume web-scraping is not encouraged;)) When having to scrape dynamic content, the data can be acquired either with a client that runs Js, or directly from the site's API. In this case he API can be found here https://frapi.fitchratings.com/search-page/search and it accepts and returns JSON data. The only requirement is that the request should have a valid referer.